# Redesign of a power supply with a 4-channel DC-DC converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, review

I'm currently working on a project involving a microprocessor, where I'm using a **5V** input via USB. To power a microprocessor and other components, I need additional voltage inputs of **3.3V**, **3.0V**, **2.5V**, and **1.1V**. Currently, I'm achieving this by using four different **SY8088** ICs, resulting in the following power supply schematic:
[image: Current schematic]
While this solution would work, it doesn't feel efficient to use four separate ICs for power conversion. Additionally, it increases the footprint and doesn't match the **QFN** package style of the rest of the ICs on my board.

In my search for a more streamlined solution, I came across the **[EA3058QD](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2006041834_Everanalog-IC-design-EA3058QDR_C575412.pdf)** IC, which appears to meet my exact requirements, as it incorporates 4 DC-DC Buck Converters. I've redesigned my power supply schematic to incorporate the EA3058QD IC, as shown here:
[image: Redesigned Schematic]

My questions are as follows:

1. Would this redesigned power supply configuration work as intended?
2. I noticed that the formula provided in the EA3058QD datasheet for calculating resistor values aligns with my previous resistor values, but should I consider any adjustments?
3. I haven't modified the capacitor values or the inductor values, as they are primarily decoupling capacitors. Is it reasonable to assume that the existing components will function adequately in this new design?

Lastly, I welcome any critiques or suggestions on my schematics, in case there are improvements or more intelligent ways to design this (I am not really experienced with creating schematics yet).

**Additional notes:**

- I'm aware that the EA3058QD IC might be obscure and challenging to obtain. However, for this personal project, I'm not concerned about its origin or availability.
- If you know of a more common "Western" alternative or have reasons to believe that this approach is not a good idea, please tell me.
- These are the full-load currents:
- **3.3v:** 50mA
- **1.1v** 100mA
- **2.5v** 40mA
- **3.0v** 40mA

Comment: *work as intended?* <-- you didn't mention what the full-load currents for each DC rail were hence, it's not possible to answer that question. Designing in obscure chips is not something I would recommend. *doesn't match the QFN package style of the rest of the ICs on my board.* <-- why is this important (would Picasso be bothered by it? If [Tracey Emin's bed](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/emin-my-bed-l03662) is on display at the Tate gallery, who are we as EEs to decide what is and isn't stylish?)

Comment: Well, I know the aesthetic concern is rather silly, but it's just not truly satisfying to have all the ICs in a QFN package except one (I know it's absolutely not important or rational, I'm probably just being a bit autistic). As for the full-load currents, you're right; I didn't mention them earlier. Here are the absolute maximum current values, although it's pretty unlikely that the processor and other ICs will consistently run at their absolute maximum:
3.3v: 50mA
1.1v: 100mA
2.5v: 40mA
3.0v: 40mA

Comment: 3.3 volts at 50 mA would waste 85 mW if you used a linear regulator. I bet the switcher wastes maybe 10 mW and is more complex and noisy. 3 volts at 40 mA would waste 80 mW. Do you really need switching supplies for all regulators? I think the 1.1 volt supply does.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but from what I've observed, most designs for this processor do use switching regulators. While theoretically, you could replace them with simpler linear regulators, it would mean starting from scratch with the power supply once again, and honestly, even the initial design would have likely worked perfectly fine. So, for now, it's mostly about aesthetics and my curiosity about those obscure ICs (and trying to make everything as compact as possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst using switching regulators seems to be a good idea for higher efficiency, it may be more problematic than advantageous if not carefully designed. They can be noisy and space-eaters, although the ones you use (or plan to use) have internal switches and are internally compensated.

> ...most designs for this processor do use switching regulators

That's probably because the processor's main use/target could be portable (battery-operated) devices which are expected to be as long-lasting as possible (No details are given, so this is just an assumption). But for a non-portable USB device that requires less than 1 W (the sum of your requirements reaches 500 mW), using switching regulators is overkill, as you are already aware *(It's good to work for curiosity and experience, though)*.

Besides, when it comes to dynamic response, a switching regulator mostly can't be better than a linear regulator, despite the fact that the switching frequencies are in MHz (therefore crossover frequencies can reach tens or hundreds of kHz). But for the current levels your system requires, we can ignore this fact for now.

> So, for now, it's mostly about aesthetics

That's totally understandable. We sometimes care about the professional look more than the functionality. However, for your application, using 4 discrete linear regulators in SOT-23-3 packages instead of fat ICs and inductors wouldn't change the professional look too much I think.

---

As for your 3 main questions:

The first thing I noticed in your second draft is that the output capacitors are in pF which is blatantly unacceptable. They must be increased to at least 22 uF, as the datasheet suggests. For inductors, although it's always good to follow the datasheet/manufacturer recommendations, using 2.2 uH instead of 1~1.5 uH wouldn't bring any problems, I'd say, because the regulators are internally compensated. Feedback resistors are fine, no need for any adjustment.

I'd still consider switching to linear regulators here (Yes, I know `it would mean starting from scratch with the power supply once again`). Also, if you are not happy with their so-called-unprofessional-look then I'm sure you can find multiple linear regulators packed into a single BGA or QFN/QFP. They must be one Digikey or Mouse search away.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. That clarifies things. I'll try my hand at linear regulators, then as well, however annoying it seems 